# Node concat no read assets

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, concatenation

I have a build project in angular that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BJJC.jpg)

then i have a script that concat the js files into a only one with this code

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const concat = require('concat');

(async function build() {
    const files = [
        './dist/cortes/runtime.js',
        './dist/cortes/polyfills.js',
        './dist/cortes/main.js',
        './dist/cortes/scripts.js'
    ]

    await fs.ensureDir('elements')

    await concat(files, 'elements/app.js')
}) ()
```

When i run that script it gives me a simple app.js that i  can import in any html as a directive like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzA3q.jpg)

All works fine at this point but when i run that html all the assets files are missing, also if i deploy that in ibm portal as a porlet, the relative routes doesnt work

if any one needs more information i have no problem to bring it

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular build should have an assets directory containing the assets at its dist directory as well. I don't think you are including it in your concat.

I think this is your problem

Comment: ye sman, the build generates me the assets folder and the index.html works fine, but when i concat to create a unique .js file with the script above the file doesnt recognize the assets